# How clear screen in QT console?

Tags: c++, qt, console-application

I need clear QT console. What is the comand?

### main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    cout<<"How delete this?";
    //system("CLS")?
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: To clear the console use `system("CLS")`. What's `QT console`?

Comment: Sorry. I did not know what system ("CLS") is working with the library QT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute:

```
QProcess::execute("CLS");
```

This will of course only work on Windows. On Linux/Unix-ish systems, you'll need to do:

```
QProcess::execute("clear");
```

If all you need to do is clear the screen, these things will work. However, if you're trying to build a more sophisticated text-based interface (where certain lines are fixed, or if you want to draw some progress indicators or the like), you'll need something more sophisticated.

- On Linux there's ncurses: http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/
- On Windows, there's a curses port call PDCurses: http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/. This will let you run nearly the same code as ncurses. If you're only focused on Windows, you can look at Windows' Console API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: `QProcess::execute("CLS");` always returns -2 on my windows 10 machine. No matter whether started from the ide or from a shell. However the command itself works when invoked in a regular `cmd` or `PowerShell` window. Are you sure, that your command works in the console window of a QCoreApplication?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, one should use

```
QProcess::execute("cmd /c cls");
```

Because plain `cls` seems not to work in an application.

On Linux, as stated above

```
QProcess::execute("clear");
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are problematic due to introducing race conditions.

This will work better: (Tested on Ubuntu. Windows, I dont know.)

```
printf("\033[2J"); // Clear Screen
printf("\033[3J"); // Clear Scrollback
```