# QProcess::execute("clear") Issue

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, qprocess

I'm writing a small console app in Qt and I want to be able to clear the terminal on a user command. I found this:

[How clear screen in QT console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028213/how-clear-screen-in-qt-console)

which almost answers my question, but its not working.

When the function "QProcess::execute("clear");" is run, I get this output to the terminal:

TERM environment variable not set.

I'm pretty new to Linux and though I've set environment variables before, its always been in the terminal before I ran the program. Here, I'd like to take care of this programmatically if possible.

My guess is that I could use QProcess::setProcessEnvironment() but I'm not really sure how exactly.

Is it possible to set the environment variables in this way, and if so how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the sample code I'm working with:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextStream qin(stdin);
    QTextStream qout(stdout);
    QString cmd;

    while(1)
    {
        cmd = qin.readLine();

        qout<<"command is: "<<cmd<<endl;

        if(cmd == "clear")
        {
            QProcess::execute("clear");
        }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why would you get that "error" but, maybe you could try `QProcess:execute("export TERM=xterm");` don't quite remember how the variable `TERM` was set; echo it on a normal terminal `echo $TERM` and go by that.

Comment: I tried QProcess::execute("export TERM=xterm"); to no avail. should it be in a specific part of the code?

Comment: Yep, before the `QProcess:execute("clear");` I guess that's what you have done without results?

Comment: does clear work from the command line at all? [This](http://pastebin.kde.org/pnjejazds) is my alternative code, but you really should fix your console.

Comment: The build environment suggestion is what I needed. If I ran the program from a new terminal process the program would work fine. But if I clicked the "Run" button in QT creator I would get the error. Turns out that I needed to add TERM = xterm to my build environment in QT creator and that fixed it right up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works fine for me. Please make sure that the clear command works fine in your console first.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QProcess::execute("clear");
    qDebug() << QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().contains("TERM");
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

Note that if you are using QtCreator, you will need add the environment variable with its value explicitly in the build settings tab. Here you can find more details in the documentation:

[QtCreator - Using Environment Variables](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-build-settings.html#using-environment-variables)

Comment: I think I see what my problem is. I'm using the "Run" button in QT creator to run the program. When I use the terminal directly and run it with ./main it works.

Comment: @DerekNowicki: does [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-build-settings.html#using-environment-variables) help? Assuming you are using QtCreator 3.0+. Although, it should be similar for previous versions, too. If it works, I will update my answer.

Comment: Yep! I just added TERM xterm to my build environment and that was all I needed. Thanks!